# Use MVP in Project,Activity.finish() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, mvp

In Activity,save() method will be call in toolbar's onOptionsItemSelected():

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_save:
            save();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

save() method:

```
@Override
public void save() {
    Snackbar.make(mContentView,"save",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    presenter.saveTask(mEditText.getText().toString(), mNpAddScore.getValue());
}
```

saveTask() in presenter:

```
@Override
public void saveTask(String content, int addScore) {
    CuteLog.tLog("content:" + content + "content.len:" +   content.length()+",addScore:" + addScore);
    if (content == null || content.length() == 0){
        view.remindNullInput();
        return;
    }

    modle.addTask(content, addScore+"");
    view.closeSelf();
    CuteLog.tLog("saveTask!!!!");
}
```

and view.closeSelf() will be called,view is the activity in begining.
closeSelf():

```
@Override
public void closeSelf() {
    CuteLog.tLog("finish");
    finish();
    CuteLog.tLog("finish2");
    return;
}
```

BUT,nonsensically,the activity doesn't finish!!
And "finish","finish2" be printed in logcat.

Why?

Comment: If i directly call finish in activity,it would work.so finish method is correct.

Comment: sorry,it's a logic mistake,my fault.and Goofyahead's answer is a good hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Finish()
```

will just queue the operation in the main thread to finish the activity but its not a synchronous operation :)

You can listen to its events with the onDestroy and checking if isFinishing() methods.

The best ways as usual is play and understand the lifecycle of activities.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: thank you ,it's a good hint ,but what should i do If i want destroy activity in my closeSelf() method?

Comment: Sorry,my fault,it's a logic mistake,left it along

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the correct `finish()` method. Try calling explicitly `Activity.this.finish()`

Comment: If i directly call finish in activity,it would work.so finish method is correct.

Comment: Maybe I was mislead by this `view.closeSelf();` and _view is the activity in begining._